# Default info for backbone view on server error

Tags: backbone.js

We have a backbone model that represents the user's account. Data for this model comes in via an API call to our backend.

If the user **is** logged in, the server returns account data and everything works fine. If the user is not logged in, the backend returns a 401. I want to have backbone handle this in some way, and use a hard coded "anoymous" data in place. How can I do this?

Would it be a better approach to modify the backend to return the dummy data instead of returning a 401?

edit: By 'handle' I mean I need to be able to run this code:

```
$.when(Account.fetch()).then(function() {alert("needs to be called");}
```

currently, the 401 causes the `then` clause to not get called.

Answer (score 0):

Backbone models have [defaults property](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-defaults). Would it work for you?

Comment: when it tries to fetch the data from the backend, it still crashes on the 401 response.

Comment: First argument of `then` is called when request completes successfully. You need to pass second parameter to `then` if you want to handle errors (which is response 401)